# SVG using jQuery, gaussian filter does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, filter

I have a problem:
I use jQuery using requirejs to draw circles. I added the gaussianblur filter for drawing. But after this no circle is visible. This is the interesting part of my code:

```
   define(['jquery'], function($) {
var canvas = $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg'));
canvas.attr({ 'version': '1.1', 'width': 1000, 'height': 500 });
$('body').append(canvas);
```

Interesting part:

::::

`$('svg').append("<defs></defs>");`

`$('defs').append("<filter id=\x27f1\x27 x=\x270\x27 y=\x270\x27></filter>");`

`$('filter').append("<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=\x2715\x27 />");`
:::::

```
require(['Circle'],function(Circle){
for( i = 0; i < zahlen.length; i+=2){
    var circ = new Circle(zahlen[i],zahlen[i+1]);
    circ.draw(canvas);
}

});
```

});

And in my circle.js:

```
draw: function(canvas) {
  canvas = canvas instanceof jQuery ? $(canvas) : canvas;

  this.circle = $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle'));
  this.circle.attr({
    filter: "url(#f1)",
    stroke:"green",
    fill: this.color
  });
```

I think it should work like this. If I delete the line "filter: "url(#f1)" the circles are visible and everything is fine (but I want this filter).
Can you spot a mistake I made?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the mistake you made is using jQuery with SVG.

Comment: What's so wrong with this? Also your answer doesn't help me.

Comment: Why not make a fiddle? Helps others to troubleshoot.

Comment: I haven't provided an answer. I've provided advice that SVG and jquery don't mix well. I suggest rewriting this without using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Did you stop to wonder why some of your code used:

```
$(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg'));
```

instead of this?

```
$("<svg></svg>");
```

Using jQuery to create elements like this does not work.  jQuery is designed to operate on HTML only and creates elements in the default (ie HTML) namespace. Whereas SVG elements **must** be in the SVG namespace.*

You need to use the `createElementNS()` approach for any SVG elements you create.

** At least until SVG2 comes out*

Comment: But the only thing not working is the filter.  If I delete the line: filter: "url(#f1)", everything works. So my question is: Why does filter: "url(#f1)", not work?

Comment: Because if you point to an invalid filter, the object is not drawn. That draws your attention to the fact that you've screwed something up.

Comment: How do I add the filter to be valid? Something like .appendChild for my SVG?

Comment: The filter not being found is because it is not a valid SVG element.  It is not a valid SVG element because it has the wrong namespace.  Create it correctly and it should work.

Comment: It's working now. I added the filter with appendChild. Thanks!